# Counting number of values in Google Sheets column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get Google Sheets to count the number of occurrences of a set of values, e.g. in [THIS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fn_8_Vgs0HXKG3k8esnIGeK2c4aXBvyyuKScAh5b9Wk/edit?usp=sharing) I would like to count how many times Unix, Linux, Windows, Mac, etc occur then also count other entries.

If anyone can help me with this or come up with a better solution to get a pie chart for each column, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With two well-ordered columns of data a pivot table should be ideal. Select ColumnsA:B in Sheet1 and Data > Pivot table report. For Rows - Add field choose say `Preferred OS`, for Columns - Add field choose `Preferred Code Editor`, for Values - Add field say `Preferred OS` and  Summarise by: COUNTA.

If you would prefer not to have a blank row at the top and a blank column one in from the left go to the top of Report Editor and Edit range... to suit.

I think you would have to copy the data out of the pivot table to build a pie chart from it, if to preserve the above arrangement. However, remove the columns field and you could chart the OSs or remove the columns field and replace the rows field with Preferred Code Editors and you could chart the Preferred Code Editors. So with two pivot tables you could have both pies.